# Software to set up strict permissions with SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

How would I set up permissions for an SSH connection? I'm thinking an SSH connection to a certain drive, and only that drive, and not being able to see all the other file systems. Just one drive. Is there software for that?
I'm using Ubuntu server 16.04.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No software needed. You can achive it by creating a [chroot jail](https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/)